# How to add Package to NUGET using GUI

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget

There are these custom libraries I keep using in a lot of my projects. I need to add it to NUGET so members of my team can get the latest versions when they need it.

Is there a command-line free way to add a visual studio project to NUGET?

Comment: You *don't* need to add your private packages to the global, public Nuget repository. Just store them in a shared folder and add the path to the folder as a Nuget source to all machines

Comment: How do I do that? That would be interesting to know. However, i'd like the packages to be in the global, public Nuget repository.

Comment: Why? That's meant for *publishing* stuff to the entire world, not for reuse inside your team. Why do you want to send your package to **me**? A private repo would make more sense. You could add [Nuget.Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server) to a web app, host eg MyGet on a site, or use [TFS Online's package management](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/27/announcing-package-management-support-for-vsotfs/)

Comment: As for adding a new source, go to "Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Settings > Package Sources" and add a new source whose path is the UNC of the share, or even a local folder

Comment: @Ikechi Michael, any update? Would you please share me the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Nuget.org is a shared source for public nuget packages. To publish the generated package to it, like the documents:

https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2016/06/28/creating-nuget-packages/

If you want to publish the package to nuget.org:

Create an account, if you don’t have one.

Go to https://www.nuget.org/packages/upload

Click Choose File and navigate to the generated nuget package 
Hit Upload

Verify the information that will be published, then click Publish

And then, the nuget package will be available online for thousands of users.

Of course, I agree with Panagiotis Kanavos' suggestion, if you want to use this packages for your team, maybe local packages would be better. For example, using the VSTS in command line here:

https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/package/nuget/publish